# Sending message from web browser plugin to android and IOS application using XMPP

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension, xmpp, jabberd2

I am developing an application that needs to send message from my web browser plugin to my android or IOS app client and get response back on the plugin.

I found XMPP as an option for that but it requires separate jabberID(JID) for each client. But I need to use the same ID lets say users Gmail ID on both the plugin and the mobile application.

Is there any work around so that same Id can be used in the plugin and mobile app or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Have you looked into using Google Cloud Messaging? (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging)

Comment: thanks adam and ya I just went through the GCM page and figured it out that gcm can be used to send notification to chrome client that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). The underlying protocol is actually [XMPP](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref), and it can efficiently push messages between your server (or client!) and Chrome, Android and iOS.

It also comes with powerful features like Device Groups, which let you send a single push message to Google and have it pushed out to numerous devices at once.

For your specific use case, check out the [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client) and [Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) docs for GCM.